# Curious why this answer is highly downvoted?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32341/11726) is highly downvoted. I'm curious to know the reason why this answer is highly downvoted.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It is very clear from comments on your answer that your answer is completely wrong. Certainly you shouldn't expect upvotes on a wrong answer.

Comment: Why downvoted can only be answered by those concerned users, others can only speculate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about whether that answer is correct or wrong. If we believe that downvotes are for wrong answers and upvotes are for right answers, we make big fools of ourselves. The dynamics of this site are such.

I don't see you giving much of your own opinion on it and just quoting from texts. That quote being in English is a major problem for many people these days (I am saying in general all over), especially after the Rajiv Malhotra phenomenon started gaining momentum.

Literal translations do sound bad and many don't like it because it hurts common sensibilities and sentiments, which are sometimes too strong. Krishna uses the word Klaibyah to chastise Arjuna in Gita and one guy went crazy! "Oh, how can he use such words!?". We simply project our material expectations on to someone who is beyond it.

It is simply being humanly conditioned to not able to see where literal translations are fine and where they are not. There are so many places in the shastras where women are glorified. I have personally heard several scholars quote from shastra about how a woman being disrespected in a family will bring ill fate to those who do it or how it is basically very easy for a woman to get to moksha even! So, any statements like you quoted must be looked at only under the guidance of a proper guru.

The third point is that people are all mostly set in their ways. Nothing can be done about it since they got there because of guna and karma.

That is why I always go for sampradayic instruction rather than just mental speculation or too much confidence in one's own sanskrit prowess.

To be honest, I did get weirded out by certain focus areas of your questions. :D